# Stata local based on other local

Tags: local, stata

I am trying to use local with the value of an earlier use of local. An example: I want to define "final" and I want it to contain "var1 var2". However, I want to define "temp" first, and reuse its contents in the definition of final.
Here is what I tried:

```
local temp "var2"

local final "var1 " `temp'
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't do what you said. To reuse the contents of a local, you must refer to that local.

Comment: I forgot to rename "ratiovars" to "temp" in the example, sorry

Comment: OK, but even so you still don't explain precisely what went wrong as far as you are concerned. The problem is the position of the closing quotation mark `"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example that works:

```
// example data
sysuse auto, clear

// what you want
local first weight
local second `first' mpg

// example use of local second
regress price `second'
```

### Edit

To answer your comment:

Yes, your problem are the double quotes. That doesn't mean, however, that using double quotes will automatically get you in trouble. For example, this will work:

```
// example data
sysuse auto, clear

// what you want
local first "weight"
local second "mpg  `first'"

// example use of local second
regress price `second'
```

Double quotes here are interpreted as string delimiters, and so will be stripped. When `local first` is (de)referenced in `` local second "mpg  `first'" ``, macro-substitution will insert `weight`, not `"weight"`. Afterwards, when `local second` is (de)referenced in `regress ...`, macro-substitution results in `mpg weight`, not `"mpg weight"`. So it's all legal syntax.

Your example contains invalid syntax. You delimit the first piece with double quotes and then continue with another piece:

```
`temp'
```

That is considered illegal.

Stata doesn't mind if we omit the double quotes in the `local` statement, which is why my first example works. See **[U] 18.3.4** Macros and expressions.

See also http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2009-01/msg00282.html and `help quotes`.

Comment: interesting, so the problem were the double quotes