# Stata do file /// Execute (do) error

Tags: comments, stata

I have a `.do` file where I have some long lines of code that are broken up to be on multiple lines.  One way to handle this is to use the `///` command at the end of the line.  However, this doesn't seem to work in the following application:

```
local abc "a b ///
    c d ///
    e f"
```

For some reason, in the do file editor, the first `///` is black and the second is green.  When I select this portion of code and hit the `Execute (do)` button to run it in Stata, I get an error.  What is to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the results of running these snippets:

```
local abc a b ///
    c d ///
    e f

display "`abc'"
```

and

```
local abc a b /*
    */ c d /*
    */ e f

display "`abc'"
```

and

```
local abc a b ///
c d ///
e f

display "`abc'"
```

In all three, Stata understands the desire to continue on the next line. What Stata doesn't like is you trying to break a string surrounded by `"` into several lines.

Check also https://stackoverflow.com/a/26143229/2077064 which might contain useful references.

Comment: Sounds good.  Dumb question, but does including the ``"``s in my example do anything different than not using ``"``s in your examples?

Comment: From **[U] 18.3.4 Macros and expressions**: "... Stata does not mind if we omit the double quotes in the local (global) statement." I recommend reading the whole entry so you understand the complete context and other things that should be of interest.

Comment: Here, for example: `local abc "abc" "d" "e" "f"`, quotes will make a difference. You can break that into several lines too, just don't do it in between corresponding `"`s.